# Sum multiple table columns using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two identical columns in multiple tables in same database.  I want to combine the sum of each column in each table independently and display the results using php.  Database name and tables:

Database name = totals 
Table names: Alabama, Tennessee, Georgia, etc...

The two relevant column fields in each table are "amount" and "tips" which contain number values.

The result I am looking for is:

Combined amount for all states = (combined total of all amounts)
Combined tips for all states = (combined total of all tips)

Please help?

Comment: "Two identical columns in multiple tables in the same database". A poor design choice, inherently.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`), SUM(`tips`) FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `amount`, SUM(`tips`) AS `tips` FROM `Alabama`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `amount`, SUM(`tips`) AS `tips` FROM `Tennessee`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `amount`, SUM(`tips`) AS `tips` FROM `Georgia`
) t
```

You might want to consider using a summary table and updating it with triggers though... This could get pretty slow if there's a lot of data.